# How come a multipart form auto converts line feed characters into CRLF

Tags: javascript, multipart

When POSTing a Multipart form via Javascript as in the following example

```js
var formdata = "A new string\nHere";
formdata.split('').map(function(x){return x.charCodeAt(0);}).join(',')
```

This will output showing that only the newline character has made it into the string as we'd expect

```
"65,32,110,101,119,32,115,116,114,105,110,103,10,72,101,114,101"
```

Now, lets take that data and place it into a Multipart form

```js
var multipartForm = new FormData();
multipartForm.append('data', formdata);
multipartForm.get('data').indexOf('\r');
// 12
```

This shows that the `\n` character has been replaced with a `\r\n` set.

Why has this taken place?

This seems to show that the mutlipart form is being opinionated about the kind of data I am sending and changing it, which I'd rather it didn't (all arguments about `\n` vs `\r\n` aside).

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519411/what-is-the-correct-newline-to-use-with-text-plain-contenttype answer your question?

Comment: I suppose it does. Thanks for the link. Given that the question relating to the same answer is semantically different, should this be closed as dupe, or the answer be the same here?

Comment: Maybe you can solve your problem by using something other than a string as the parameter.

Comment: Try using a `Blob` instead. That should use a binary or base64 representation, and shouldn't change the contents.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that!