# How to return text with line break with Grape API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am trying to create an endpoint where the response body is just a string with line breaks, but the response keeps showing the \n character.

My endpoint code:

```
get '' do
  header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  body("Hello\nWorld")
end
```

And this is the response I see in Postman:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work like I wanted with the following code:

```
get '' do
  env['api.format'] = :binary
  header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  body("Hello\nWorld")
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

\n is a new line character for UNIX systems, and in [RFC2046](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt) is specified that new line characters in text/plain format should use \r\n (Windows style new line).

So In Your case server should return "Hello\r\nWorld"

For more verbose answer check this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519411/what-is-the-correct-newline-to-use-with-text-plain-contenttype)